# Where can I select my personal plugins in GIMP?

Tags: python, ubuntu, gimp, gimpfu

I have been trying to run [these sample scripts](http://gimpbook.com/scripting/) (specially `helloworld.py` and `pytemplate.py`) to get the hang on using python code in GIMP. I'm specially interested in `pytemplate.py` which is intended to show how to do something over an existing image (hopefully, the current state of the image which has the focus)

As far as I know, I have to place them in `~/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/` (in my GIMP's personal folder) and give them run permissions (`chmod +x somescript.py`).

The `gimpfu.register()` function has a kwarg that seems to control where the "trigger option" would appear. It looks like:

```
menu="<Image>/Filters/Enhance"
```

However, my GIMP has the menus in Spanish language, somehow this makes me being afraid that it can interfere in rendering the "trigger"... Anyway, I restarted GIMP  and tried to follow the menu path from my GIMP's main window's menu and didn't find anything at all.

**The point is:** What else do I have to do to run the script and see what happens? Can I actually control where the "trigger option" to run my script will appear with `menu` kwarg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed permissions and they were 400. I was sure to have executed `chmod +x *py`. **Well, finally I found the "triggers"**.

Comment: "should I erase it now?" the place to ask that question is in the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Also, your question is probably more relevant in [Graphics Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) than in StackOverflow, I think.

Comment: Well, it was a retoric question for myself... my bad. I was thinking what to do about it (options in mind where: flag it? meta? Delete it directly? Thanks for helping take the right decision :)

Comment: Thanks for informing of Graphics Design existence. However,my speciality is to write code (I'm not designer), and I thought it looked like a "python's gimpfu module" specific question. Maybe my guess was a bad call... I'll check it out in Graphic's design Help Center...

Comment: I opened a [meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309050/would-it-be-an-error-to-delete-directly-my-question) in order to see what would be the most wise action to take about this kind of questions...